# How to convert and map javascript object to a proper one

Tags: javascript

I have main object called `data`. Under `data` object I have criticalErrorsData which is a type of array.
Inside that object I have multiple objects like this:

```
[
    {
        "EmployeeName": {
            "FirstName": "Joe",
            "LastName": "Doe",
            "Suffix": null
        },
        "CriticalErrorCount": 4,
        "HomeDepartment": "Belgrade",
        "SupervisorName": {
            "FirstName": "Test",
            "LastName": "Test",
            "Suffix": null
        }
    }
]
```

I need to perform `.forEach()` for all these items inside data.criticalErrorsData and to map it like this:

```
const criticalErrorsData = [
    { supervisor:SupervisorName.FirstName + SupervisorName.LastName, department: HomeDepartment, errors: CriticalErrorCount, employee: EmployeeName.FirstName+EmployeeName.LastName },
    { ... },
    { ... }
  ];
```

How can I achieve this? Sould I need to use only.map() function or I need to introduce a helper variable also?

Example of structure of my objects:
data
{
CriticalErrorsData:
{
[0] - this object I want to map
[1] - this object I want to map
[2] - this object I want to map
...  - as many as CriticalErrorsData has them
}
}

I also tried something like this:

```
      const test = receivedData.criticalErrorsData.map(obj => ({
        
        supervisor: obj.SupervisorName.FirstName + obj.SupervisorName.LastName,
        department: obj.HomeDepartment,
        errors: obj.CriticalErrorCount,
        employee: obj.EmployeeName.FirstName + obj.EmployeeName.LastName
      })
      );
        console.log(test);
```

Comment: You don't want a space between the first and last names?

Comment: No, its not neccessery, I can add it later, but I cant figure it out how to create a dynamic property object called for example supervisor..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `map()`. Destructuring in the parameter list will allow you to refer to the properties the way you show.

```js
const data = {
  criticalErrorsData: [{
    "EmployeeName": {
      "FirstName": "Joe",
      "LastName": "Doe",
      "Suffix": null
    },
    "CriticalErrorCount": 4,
    "HomeDepartment": "Belgrade",
    "SupervisorName": {
      "FirstName": "Test",
      "LastName": "Test",
      "Suffix": null
    }
  }]
};

criticalErrorsData = data.criticalErrorsData.map(({
  SupervisorName,
  CriticalErrorCount,
  HomeDepartment,
  EmployeeName
}) => ({
  supervisor: SupervisorName.FirstName + SupervisorName.LastName,
  department: HomeDepartment,
  errors: CriticalErrorCount,
  employee: EmployeeName.FirstName + EmployeeName.LastName
}));

criticalErrorsData.forEach(item => console.log(item.supervisor));
```

Comment: Can you just please update your answer how to access it through foreach loop? Because this object resides in data.CricitalErrors[0],[1]... tnx

Comment: I've added a `forEach()`

Comment: No, I mean is that I have `mainObjects` under some other object, and I need to put `.map()` function into foreach loop

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's nested in another object, just use the full path to it. `someObject.mainObjects.map()`

Comment: Please update the quesiton to show what you really have and what the result should be. I can't figure it out from these comments.

Comment: Please see my updated question. sorry for poor description.

Comment: I've updated the answer to match the structure of the data. It doesn't really change the algorithm in any way, just the way you reference the array that you're mapping.